# C# Using a proxy for WebClient

Tags: c#, proxy, webclient

This is the code I have right now

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString("http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/"));
}
```

Now, I would like to put in 2 options for a proxy.

1. An option to either a standard IP:Proxy
2. An option with authentication.

I just can't seem to figure out how to connect it with the above code

Answer (score 3):

```
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
        client.Proxy = new WebProxy("31.4.5.26", 8080); // proxy's host,port
        client.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("proxyuser", "proxypassword");
        Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString("http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/"));
    }
```

Works fine for me!